# replace parts of url with sed in a file

Tags: regex, sed, command-line

I have a file full of urls that looks like this:

```
https://testing/this/string/for/now
```

which I need to have them all replaced using sed specifically, to:

```
https://testing/this/now
```

and save the file at the end with the updated content. So actually remove
whatever content exists in the 'string' and 'for'(no matter their length might be), but keep the latter 'now' part of the url.

Thanks in advance.

Vincent

Comment: Are they all starting with `https://testing/` ?

Comment: Yes. Actually all start with https://testing/this/
Not sure how to make https appear here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this sed command to remove 2 paths after `https://testing/this/`:

```
sed -i.bak 's|\(https://testing/this/\)[^/]*/[^/]*/|\1|'' file
```

**Explanation:**

```
\(https://testing/this/\)  # match and group https://testing/this/
[^/]*/                     # match 0 or more of any character that is not /
[^/]*/                     # match 0 or more of any character that is not /
```

In replacement we're using `\1` which is back-reference to first capturing group.

**Example:**

```
s='https://testing/this/string/for/now'
sed 's|\(https://testing/this/\)[^/]*/[^/]*/|\1|' <<< "$s"
https://testing/this/now
```

Comment: I advise against recommending tilde as a separator for this sort of pattern, since tilde is the default user directory indicator in URLs.

Comment: May I kindly ask you to provide an explanation please, as I have been recently introduced in sed and I struggle to get a grasp around it. For instance, what the ~ means at the beginning and end of the expression?

Comment: Also, what about the next part [^/]*/[^/]*/~\1~

Comment: Thank you very much anubhava. By \1 and reference to first capturing group, do you literally mean the group https://testing/this/  ? I am wondering how does it references\remembers the 'now' part.

Comment: We are only capturing `https://testing/this/` in `\1`. `now` part is not captured or matched in pattern so it remains unaffected. This `sed` pattern is only matching upto `https://testing/this/anything/anything/`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution using `cut`:

```
# echo https://testing/this/string/for/now | cut -d/ -f1-4,7
https://testing/this/now
```

To process a file, just run `cut -d/ -f1-4,7 < input.txt > output.txt`.